# Implementing 2 exec function inside a php function

Tags: php

I want to implement 2 exec function inside a php function something like

```
public function definition($source){
     shell_exec("");
     shell_exec("");
}
```

Now what I want is to implement it by order, first to execute one then after the first is executed, execute the second. In the first I would like to implement cd( move to folder ) under windows, something like

```
    public function definition($source){
         shell_exec("cd C:\myfolder");
         shell_exec("");
    }
enter code here
```

and in the second I would like to run python script with two params, the first one is a python script which is located in the folder I have just moved to and the second one is the image located in the same folder, something like

```
public function definition($source){
     shell_exec("cd C:\myfolder");
     shell_exec("python myScript.py myImage.jpg");
}
```

Now what I would like to is to pass the parameter from the function definition to the 2nd python argument something like

```
public function definition($source){
     shell_exec("cd C:\myfolder");
     shell_exec("python myScript.py".$source);
}
```

Now I would like to hear your solution to what I need, I have tried my best but didn't manage to solve it. Thank you on your help and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run two commands at once on windows using an &.  So instead of doing two shell_exec you would do one.  It takes the form.

```
shell_exec('CMD1 & CMD2');
```

I believe every time you do shell_exec it opens a new shell, so when you try to run your python command you are actually in the wrong directory.

If that doesn't work you might also try using two & symbols instead of one.

```
shell_exec('CMD1 && CMD2');
```

Hopefully that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you can do it like this:

```
$cmd = 'command to run';
exec( 'bash -c "nohup $cmd > /dev/null 2>&1 &"' );
```

This will only progress once the exec command has completed.

I don't know if you can do this on Windows, but if you can, the end part will probably be like:

```
$cmd = 'command to run';
exec( 'bash -c "$cmd > nul 2>&1 &"' );
```

However, I am not sure what the equivalent of **'bash -c'** would be.

Possible Windows solution:

```
$shell = new COM( "WScript.Shell" );
$shell->run( "your command", 0, false );
```

You could also do this:

```
public function definition( $source )
{
     chdir( 'C:\myfolder' );
     shell_exec( 'python myScript.py' . $source );
     # chdir back to your script directory if needed
}
```

I am not sure if PHP will chdir to 'C:\myfolder' using that command.

Comment: This wasn't my vote down. I have given to you +1 for at least trying even though it isn't very helpful to me. :/

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't be of more help, as I do not use Windows. The first code is what I use on Linux. I've updated it with a version of this, which may work on Windows (guessing).

Comment: There is no need to sorry! Thank you on your help! :)